# What is causing Safari to crash when dragging image or text?

Tags: display, safari, ui

I've recently been encountering an issue whereby dragging either an image or selected text on a webpage causes Safari (10.1, on El Capitan 10.11.6) to force reload the page (not a real 'crash', I guess, but a semi-crash). The page gets a slim alert banner at the top saying “A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded” and a modal alert box pops up saying “Safari Web Content quit unexpectedly. Click Report to see more detailed information and to send a report to Apple.”

I've got a two screen setup with this iMac: the iMac's own retina screen, and a 'regular' resolution screen connected via VGA-thunderbolt adaptor. Further investigation has revealed that the ‘drag crash’ only occurs if the browser window is on the Retina screen. And it only seems to happen in Safari, not Chrome.

A workaround would be to move the browser to the regular screen before dragging anything, but that doesn't really gel with my workflow.

Anyone have any ideas how I can stop this from happening?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it only that webpage or does it happen in other pages?

Comment: All pages. But only on a retina screen. It seems to be a known issue; https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7932475

Comment: Being that it's a known bug, the only thing you can do is work around it by either manually saving the image to a folder (i.e. Desktop) or use a different browser.

Comment: Hmm, suspected that might be the case. I was hoping that there might be some obscure combination of enabling/disabling X,Y and Z that would solve it. Ho hum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have something to do with the color profile.
Changing it to either Generic RGB or sRGB IEC61966-2.1 prevents the crash, if you can live with the uncalibrated color scheme.

More here:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/31703564#message31703564

Comment: Thanks AndreasT; I'd actually recently found that exact same thread. Good to know that there is a fix in the works (Safari 10.1.1) since an uncalibrated workflow will be a ‘show-stopper’ problem for many Mac users.